# Is there a way to cause scintillation of air particles using an artificial source?

Tags: radiation

Is there an artificial source that can cause scintillation of air (nitrogen, oxygen, etc. )?  What does it emit and what is the range?

Comment: What is the range of the LHC beam in air? Based on the length of the beam dump is must be thousands of meters, but I never calculated the energy loss in air. Cosmic rays can make air scintillate for tens of kilometers. Somehow it seems to me, though, that you are looking for something more "handy" and safe? :-)

Comment: Could a passive sensor measure cosmic rays in a "side scatter" technique?

Comment: Somewhat less hazardous than @CuriousOne suggest, a variety of lower energy accelerators bring beams of protons and alphas out into air to perform Rutherford Backscattering. See, for example, http://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/may-2015/the-accelerator-in-the-louvre for application to art objects. You get scintillation from that.  Also, many cyclotrons have external beams.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "passive sensor", but if you want to see what physics experiments look like that are actually detecting this scintillation, look no further than here: http://www.physics.adelaide.edu.au/astrophysics/images/hires/image4_large.jpg. How big are your pockets?

Comment: Active sensors emit before measuring returns. Passive transduce incoming phenomena.